# jQuery Mobile tap on element highlights element in next page?

Tags: jquery-mobile, transition, tap

I have a Android app created with Phonegap (3.1.0) and jQuery Mobile (1.4.0), using a single page layout (so each page has its own HTML file).

This is what happens:

- **page1.html** has a button at position X-Y. This button performs a `$.mobile.pageChange('page2.html);` on click (tap in the case of touch devices)
- **page2.html** has a list of elements using the jQuery Mobile **list-view** data-role
- When tapping the button on **page1**, the transition occurs as it should, showing **page2**. The weird thing is that the element of the list whose position is the same as the tapped button in **page1** shows directly highlighted (the same highlight of when you tap a list element).

Technically no element of that list should be highlighted until the user taps it, so for some reason the page is "remembering" the last tapped position on the screen and after a transition, shows whatever element is in that same position as if it had been tapped already.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly I don't have a answer for this as of yet. But I can confirm that the replacement for :

```
$.mobile.pageChange (which is now depreciated)
```

also displays the same problem:

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "page2.html", { transition: "none" });
```

Also I experience the same problem with buttons within the header. If a there is a button within the header of **page2** and a button was clicked in same location on **page1** the highlighting sticks and/or is activated on said button.

A further problem I have found depends on how `$.mobile.pageChange` or `$.mobile.pageContainer` are called. If using onclick then the highlighting problem occurs. However if using ontouchend on **page1** I find that if a button is placed in the same location of **page2** the button is not only highlighted but actually clicked/tapped.

Comment: it's a little annoying... I've tried using 'tap' events instead of 'click' for those buttons with the same exact result...

Comment: I've also discovered that if you have a collapsible listview on **page2** and a button in the same location on **page1** the listview will expand. Or in other words the click will be applied twice, on the first and second page.

Also to clarify I am also using phonegap alongside jquery.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem with the current version jqm 1.4.5.

Basically the tapped spot on mobile would highlight elements on the next page - using multiple-page version. Testing this on PC confirmed my suspicion that it's the last spot you have your mouse hover, so the last spot where you clicked a button on the previous page. This led to some other bugs in my case -> sometimes the highlighted element would stay highlighted even when tapping elsewhere on the page.

Trying out removing classes and messing with the JS in general as suggested in numerous search results didn't work for me. In the end I made some simple CSS-changes in a custom file - inserted after jqm css files.

I used Firebug to find the according classes since jqm rewrites your html. In my case I removed the hover effect by assigning fixed background colors, but highlighted all tapped elements in my form for better navigation.

```
/* quick fix 'tap -> highlights element next page'-bug
 * : change on/off states to a fixed background color
 * so we avoid hover mechanisms
 * 'on'-elements stay highlighted
*/
html body .ui-controlgroup-vertical .ui-radio-on,
html body .ui-checkbox-on,
html body .ui-collapsible .ui-collapsible-heading .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle { /* selected radio/checkbox/collapsible */
    background-color: #eee !important;
}

html body .ui-radio-off,
html body .ui-checkbox-off,
html body .ui-collapsible-collapsed .ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle { /* all unselected radio/checkbox/collapsible */
    background-color: #f6f6f6 !important;
}

html body .ui-collapsible .ui-collapsible-heading .ui-btn-active { /* collapsible tap state */
    background-color: #38c !important;
}
```

Obviously, this is a customized fix for my needs, so you may need to check what you want changed in your own form. This worked for me and will maybe keep others from sprouting gray hair - as happened to me!

(I only tested this on PC and Android devices, needs checking on IOS)